# cuando valido en campo email no se quita la alerta

Tags: javascript

cuando introduzco el email no se quita la alerta email no es valido , me gustaría recibir algún consejo para mejorarlo gracias

cuando introduzco bien el email se tiene que quitar la alerta pero no se quita me gustaría saber donde esta el error

el problema esta en la función validarEmail no se que esta mal.

cuando introduzco el email correctamente no se quita la alerta

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
//Seleccionar los elementos de la interfaz
const inputEmail = document.querySelector("#email");
const inputAsunto = document.querySelector("#asunto");
const inputMensaje = document.querySelector("#mensaje");
const formulario = document.querySelector("#formulario");

inputEmail.addEventListener("blur",validar);
inputAsunto.addEventListener("blur",validar);
inputMensaje.addEventListener("blur",validar);

function validar(e) {
    if(e.target.value.trim() === "") {
        mostrarAlerta(`El campo ${e.target.id} es obligatorio`,e.target.parentElement);
        return;
    }
     
    if(e.target.id ===  "email"  && !validarEmail(e.target.value)) {
        mostrarAlerta("El email no es valido", e.target.parentElement);
        return;     
    }

   limpiarAlerta(e.target.parentElement); 





    //Asignar los valores
    //email[e.target.name] = e.target.value.trim().toLowercase();
    //console.log(email);
}


function mostrarAlerta(mensaje, referencia) {
         
    limpiarAlerta(referencia);
    //generar alerta HTML
    const error = document.createElement("P");
    error.textContent = mensaje;
    error.classList.add("bg-red-600","text-white", "p-2","text-center");
    referencia.appendChild(error);
} 

function limpiarAlerta(referencia){
    // Comprueba si ya existe una alerta

    const alerta = referencia.querySelector(".bg-red-600");
    if(alerta) {
       alerta.remove();
    }    

}

function validarEmail(email) {
   const regex = /^\w+([.-_+]?\w+)*@\w+([.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,10})+$/;
   const resultado = regex.test(email);
   console.log(resultado);
}
    
});
```

Comment: Tu función `validarEmail()` no está retornando nada, debes retornar el valor colocando `return resultado;` al final, saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema esta en la funcion validaremail ya que deberia retornar verdadero o falso para que la alerta se quite, y en tu funcion solo escribes en el console.log(resultado).

```
function validarEmail(email) {
   const regex = /^\w+([.-_+]?\w+)*@\w+([.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,10})+$/;
   const resultado = regex.test(email);
   console.log(resultado); <---- ESTO ES LO QUE TE COMENTE
}
```

Ahora bien, segun tu codigo para devolver un verdadero o falso de tu regex.test deberia quedar asi:

```
function validarEmail(email) {
   const regex = /^\w+([.-_+]?\w+)*@\w+([.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,10})+$/;
   return regex.test(email);
}
```

Comment: muchas gracias si me funciono